# Таблица дат, разница даты между текущей и наибольшей - forEach, function

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня таблица с датами:

HTML-Code:

```
<table>
<tr class= "stroka">
 <td class= "date_z">2021-07-01</td>
 <td class= "date_pz1"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz2"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz3"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz4"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz5"></td>
 <td class = "days">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class= "stroka">
 <td class= "date_z">2021-07-01</td>
 <td class= "date_pz1">2021-07-07</td>
 <td class= "date_pz2"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz3"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz4"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz5"></td>
 <td class = "days">0</td>
</tr>
<tr class= "stroka">
 <td class= "date_z">2021-07-02</td>
 <td class= "date_pz1">2021-07-04</td>
 <td class= "date_pz2">2021-07-05</td>
 <td class= "date_pz3"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz4"></td>
 <td class= "date_pz5"></td>
 <td class = "days">0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

В ней мне нужно организовать подсчёт дат между наибольшей в строке и текущей датой, разницу в днях занести в ячейку days.

JS-Code:

```
// ПОЛУЧАЕМ ТЕКУЩУЮ ДАТУ

function zero_first_format(value)
{
    if (value < 10)
    {
        value='0'+value;
    }
    return value;
}

function date_time()
{
    var current_datetime = new Date();
    var day = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getDate());
    var month = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getMonth()+1);
    var year = current_datetime.getFullYear();
    return year+"-"+month+"-"+day;
}

let dateNow = date_time(); // текущую дату засунули в переменную
let table = document.querySelectorAll('tr'); // выбрали строки
function calcSumm () {

    table.forEach (element => { // т.е. для каждого элемента выбранных строк производим это
        
        let date_zagruz = document.querySelector('.date_z').innerText;
        let date_pz1 = document.querySelector('.date_pz1').innerText;
        let date_pz2 = document.querySelector('.date_pz2').innerText;
        let date_pz3 = document.querySelector('.date_pz3').innerText;
        
        if (date_zagruz > date_pz1) {
            var date1m = moment(dateNow,'YYYY-M-D'); 
            var date2m = moment(date_zagruz,'YYYY-M-D');
            var diffDays = date1m.diff(date2m, 'days');

        } else if (date_pz1 > date_pz2) {
            var date1m = moment(dateNow,'YYYY-M-D'); 
            var date2m = moment(date_pz1,'YYYY-M-D');
            var diffDays = date1m.diff(date2m, 'days');

        } else if (date_pz2 > date_pz3) {
            var date1m = moment(dateNow,'YYYY-M-D'); 
            var date2m = moment(date_pz2,'YYYY-M-D');
            var diffDays = date1m.diff(date2m, 'days');
        }
        element.innerHTML = diffDays; // вставляем полученную разницу
    })
}

calcSumm();
```

Таким образом производится рассчёт, и я получаю разницу в строки. Мне нужно, чтобы рассчёт был в ячейке days, пробывал делать так:

```
const tdDays = document.querySelector('.days'); // для каждой строки выбрать ячейку
tdDays.innerHTML = diffDays; // вставляем полученную разницу из условия
```

Но на деле я получаю результат лишь в первую строку, в останольном, дальше рассчёт не производится. Помогите разобраться в чем проблема? В JS - нубик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let date_zagruz = element.querySelector('.date_z').innerText;
...
element.querySelector('.days').innerHTML = diffDays;
```

Comment: О спасибо друг, а то я ж думаю вроде по логике вещей все верно, но что за черт.)

Comment: @EVG_JS Пожалуйста. Успехов.